# When I pass a parameter to the JS controller via event.currentTarget.dataset it gives undefined

Tags: lightning, javascript, event, parameters

In an aura:iteration, I pass the selected Order to the JS controller as in the code:

```
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.ordersAlt}" var="item">
    <tr class="slds-hint-parent">
        <td data-label="Selected">
            <div class="slds-truncate" title="Selected"><input type="checkbox" checked="true" name="options" id="checkbox-01" value="checkbox-01" tabindex="0" aria-labelledby="check-button-label-01 column-group-header" onchange="{! c.selectOrder }" data-order ="{!item}"/></div>
        </td>
        <th data-label="Order Id" scope="row">
            <div class="slds-truncate" title="Order Id">
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" tabindex="-1">{!item.Id}</a>
            </div>
        </th>
    </tr>
   </aura:iteration>
```

For {!item.Id} I get a result, so the iteration works fine. The function in the controller looks like this:

```
selectOrder : function(component, event, helper) {

        var order = event.currentTarget.dataset.order;
        var selectedOrders = component.get("v.selectedOrders");

        var listOrderIds = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < selectedOrders.length; i += 1){
            listOrderIds.push(selectedOrders[i].Id);
            console.log('selectedOrders[i].Id '+selectedOrders[i].Id);
        }

        var index = listOrderIds.indexOf(order.Id);
        console.log('order.Id '+order.Id)

        console.log("index "+index); 
        //console.log("selectedOrders before "+selectedOrders); 

    }
```

Everything works fine. When I pass the parameter via `data-order ="{!item.Id}"` that also works. Just if I use `data-order ="{!item}"` I get the result of undefined for order.Id. How can I modify so that the code works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass ONLY strings as attribute values and so if you are passing the whole object as attribute value, it will be stored as ***[object Object]*** *string* and `[object Object].Id` does not make any sense and so it will return `undefined`.

You should pass the `Id` by using `data-order ="{!item.Id}"` and get the record through Id as below:

```
let orderId = event.currentTarget.dataset.order;
var ordersAlt = component.get("v.ordersAlt");  // list of records which are used in iteration
let clickedRecord = ordersAlt.find(item => item.Id===orderId);
console.log(clickedRecord.Id); // will give you correct Id
```

Here is the [playground link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/rDXf2BqTn/1/edit) if it helps (in LWC)

Comment: Ok, thanks, so if I need the entire object I need to get it from an Apex controller?

Comment: You already have the list `ordersAlt`. So you can get it by using `find` javascript function as shown. And yes if it suits your requirment you can pass the order Id to apex controller and query for the record.

Comment: ordersAlt may not contain the order, so I need the information from somewhere else. Thanks for the response.